# How should I deal with multiple order-dependent conditions?

Tags: javascript, performance, readability

I have multiple concurrent conditions in which the order is dependent on the conditions. I've come up with multiple approaches to deal with this issue and I need help choosing the best possible solution out of several that I have prepared. Things to consider are: Performance, Re-usability, Readability, Memory Consumption.

Approach 1: define multiple nested switch cases

```
var collision = {
    detect1: function(subject, target){
        // multiple switch cases
        var shapes = {};
        shapes[subject.type] = subject;
        shapes[target.type] = target;

        switch(subject.type) {
            case 'rectangle':
                switch(target.type) {
                    case 'ellipse':
                        return this.rectWithEllipse(subject, target);
                }
                break;
            case 'ellipse':
                switch(target.type) {
                    case 'rectangle':
                        return this.rectWithEllipse(target, subject);
                }
        }
    },
```

Approach 2: Store types in an object registry and switch order based on parameter testing

```
    detect2: function(subject, target){
        // object registry and place switch
        var shapes = {};
        shapes[subject.type] = subject;
        shapes[target.type] = target;

        var shape1 = subject;
        var shape2 = target;

        var reverseShapeOrder = function() {
            shape2 = target;
            shape1 = subject;
        };

        if ( shapes.rectangle && shapes.ellipse ) {
            if (subject.type === 'ellipse') {
                reverseShapeOrder();
                return this.rectWithEllipse(shape1, shape2);
            }
        }
    },
```

Approach 3: concatenate types to a string and switch order based on indexOf testing for order.

```
    detect3: function(subject, target) {
        // string concat and decoding with place switch
        var shapeString = subject.type + target.type;

        var rectIndex =  shapeString.indexOf('rectangle');
        var ellipseIndex = shapeString.indexOf('ellipse');
        var pointIndex = shapeString.indexOf('point');

        var shape1 = subject;
        var shape2 = target;

        var reverseShapeOrder = function() {
            shape2 = target;
            shape1 = subject;
        };

        if (rectIndex && ellipseIndex) {
            if (ellipseIndex < rectIndex) {
                reverseShapeOrder();
            }
            return this.rectWithEllipse(shape1, shape2);
        }
    },
```

Approach 4: Standard traditional if-else statements

```
    // traditional logic
    detect4: function(subject, target) {
        if (subject.type === 'rectangle'  && target.type === 'ellipse') {
            return this.rectWithEllipse(subject, target);
        }
        else if (subject.type ==='ellipse' && target.type === 'rectangle') {
            return this.rectWithEllipse(target, subject);
        }
    },
    rectWithEllipse: function(rect, ellipse) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Approach 5: On the fly selector with reference function (thanks for the on-the-fly selector suggestion @Bergi)

```
detect5: function(subject, target) {
        return this[subject.type + '_with_' + target.type](subject, target);
    },
    rect_with_ellipse: function(rect, ellipse) {
        return false;
    },
    ellipse_with_rect: function(rect, ellipse) {
        this.rect_with_ellipse(ellipse, rect);
    }
};
```

Please help me select the best solution and understand why it is best. Thanks

Keep in mind that the full list of combinations will be larger like so:

```
rectWithPoint: function(rect, point) {
    return false;
},
rectWithEllipse: function(rect, ellipse) {
    return false;
},
rectWithRect: function(rect, rect) {
    return false;
},
ellipseWithPoint: function(ellipse, point) {
    return false;
},
ellipseWithEllipse: function(ellipse, ellipse) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Approach five: Just call `this[subject.type + "With" + target.type](target, subject)` (possibly with some name-fiddling)

Comment: Side question: is this code intended to be used as-is, or passed through Google Closure Compiler or a similar tool?

Comment: The code will be used as is for now. But eventually I'd want to compile all my code as a matter of course. @Arnauld

Comment: @Bergi see what I've added

Comment: Assuming Google Closure Compiler in ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS mode, I would consider using integers instead of strings for all the types, using declarations such as `/** @const */ var ELLIPSE = 0;`to preserve readability. That would allow you to do things such as `switch(type0 | (type1 << 4)) { case ELLIPSE | (RECTANGLE << 4): ... }`, where the case value will be replaced by a single integer in the compiled source.

Comment: @Arnauld Very nice idea man. So basically, I can run detection on the second variable, because its shifted 4 to the left. But why specifically shift it by 4?

Also, i assume this is meant to be used with a nested switch case

Comment: The shift by 4 was just an example, assuming up to 16 different possible types. It's meant for a single switch(), since it allows you to test two types at once (or even more, as long as the final mask fits in a 32-bit integer).

Comment: @Arnauld fair enough. A bit mask is a nice idea actually. And I hadnt thought of shifting to indicate the value of the second variable. But there still remains the issue of entering the variables in the correct order. Would you suggest setting up proxy functions to do that, or a mapping such as was shown in the selected answer, or just a nested switch case?

Comment: There are plenty of ways of doing it, really, and I'm not sure which one is the best. You could do `switch(type0 < type1 ? type0 | (type1 << 4) : type1 | (type0 << 4))` to make sure that the type with the lowest ID goes into the least significant bits. Or you could just put two consecutive 'case' for both combinations, followed by their common code block.

Comment: @Arnauld wow man, nice solution. I probably won't use this because of readability issues. But in a performance sensitive situation this would be super-awesome. Here take some geek-points :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define a mapping as follows, which will make it easy to extend:

```
targets: {
  rectangle: {
    point: function rectWithPoint(rect, point) {
      return false;
    },
    ellipse: function rectWithEllipse(rect, ellipse) {
      return false;
    },
    rectangle: function rectWithRect(rectLhs, rectRhs) {
      return false;
    }
  },
  ellipse: {
    point: function ellipseWithPoint(ellipse, point) {
      return false;
    },
    ellipse: function ellipseWithEllipse(ellipseLhs, ellipseRhs) {
      return false;
    }
  }
},

detect5: function (subject, target) {
  var tmp, candidates = this.targets[subject];

  if (!candidates) {
    tmp = subject;
    subject = target;
    target = tmp;
    candidates = this.targets[subject];
  }

  if (candidates && candidates.hasOwnProperty(target)) {
    return candidates[target].call(this, subject, target);
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach I had not thought of. I'm going to take a bit of time to consider it. What are the disadvantages and advantages of this approach over the other ones?

Comment: To add a new collision detector, you only need to define one pair of keys: (subject -> target) -> predicate.  This will keep your code DRY, simple, and concise as you support many-more shapes.  It's a common approach to modeling graphs, of which this is a simple kind.

Comment: In addition, I would say that this is far and away the most readable approach

Comment: I'm still curious to hear what other people have to say. But this is pretty sound reasoning. Thanks alot :) @Dylon

Comment: @Dylon what does the Rhs and Lhs stand for btw ?

Comment: Right-hand-side and left-hand-side, respectively.  They are traditional, parameter names for binary operations.  For example, lhs + rhs, lhs * rhs, etc.

Comment: @yosefrow: It's pretty much similar to my suggestion. Whether flattened or not shouldn't make a huge difference, it's definitely the right way to go.

Comment: @Bergi yeah. I particularly like the way this is implemented, as it allows for really easy and readable extension. Flat might work for just a few. But in this case where there will be many cases, I think a map like this is really the way to go. It also helps keep track of which cases you've covered already.